# Angular Social Login (with Google) + Angular Guards

Tags: angular, rxjs, google-signin, angular-social-login

I'm trying to implement an Angular Guard using the Angular Social Login npm package:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: SocialAuthService) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('guard');
    return this.authService.authState.pipe(
      map((socialUser: SocialUser) => {
        console.log('map');
        return !!socialUser;
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return of(false);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

I can see `guard` being printed to the console. However, I can't see `map` printed to the console. Why?

If I do:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: SocialAuthService) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('guard');
    return new Observable<boolean>((subscriber) => {
      console.log('subscriber');
      subscriber.next(true);
    });
  }
}
```

I can see `subscriber` being printed to the console.

What am I doing wrong?

I want to be able to add this Guard to a route. If a user is not logged in, it would be redirected to a login page (I know I'm not yet implementing that logic; I've tried and failed since it seems I'm not getting an Observable with values?). Note that I'm using Google as a provider for this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    IndexPageComponent,
    SearchPageComponent,
    InputKeywordsComponent,
    DisplayNewsListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SocialLoginModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
      useValue: {
        autoLogin: false,
        providers: [
          {
            id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
              'superVerySecret'
            ),
          },
        ],
      } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And the routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: IndexPageComponent },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchPageComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [LoginGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

PS1: I can login just fine.

PS2:

- @angular/core@12.2.13
- @rxjs@6.6.7
- angularx-social-login@4.0.1

Comment: "I can see guard being printed to the console. However, I can't see map printed to the console" why are you not using an IDE and breakpointing? I am not sating that that would answer you, because the second breakpoint would not be hit, but "debug by print"  went out of style a few decades ago, and getting into the habit of using a debugger will benefit you immensely. Hmmm, is `pipe` a promise/asynch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to [@msmiechowski](https://github.com/msmiechowski) for helping me reaching a solution in [this](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/issues/464) GitHub issue.

My solution:

```js
// login.guard.ts

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private loginService: LoginService) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.loginService.checkAuthState()) {
      return of(true);
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      return of(false);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// login.service.ts

// ...

checkAuthState(): boolean {
  let flag = false;
  this.authService.authState.subscribe({
    next: (socialUser: SocialUser) => {
      if (socialUser) {
        flag = true;
      }
    },
    error: (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    },
    complete: () => {
      console.log('Complete!');
    },
  });
  return flag;
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a `take(1)` before your map, to get the latest value of `this.authService.authState` i.e.:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: SocialAuthService) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('guard');
    return this.authService.authState.pipe(
      take(1), // <--- add this line
      map((socialUser: SocialUser) => {
        console.log('map');
        return !!socialUser;
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return of(false);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working. I've also tried (and failed) with other operators like filter, find, takeLast, isEmpty, defaultIfEmpty..

Comment: Are you certain `this.authService.authState` is receiving a value before or while your guard is being evaluated? That sounds like the problem to me. If you want to set up a stackblitz I could take a look for you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering. Been a bit busy with work. I'll let you know if I'll have the time to set up the stackblitz. Thank you for the availability though!